# Why does if($signup->signup(...)) return with the message "Signup failed" while signup was successful?

Tags: php, pdo

So I've noticed something in `php` that I don't really understand

Say I have a simple signup `function` like this:

```
Class signup extends Connect{
function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
parent::connect();
}
function signup($username,$password){
$res=$this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password) 
VALUES(?,?)");
$res->bindparam(1,$username);
$res->bindparam(2,$password); 
$res->execute();
}
}
```

And in another file, I want to check whether the signup was successful like this:

```
require("signup.php");
$signup=new signup();
if($signup->signup(...)){
echo "Signed up";
}
else{
echo "Signup failed";
}
```

And this statement will return with **Sigup failed** if I have succesfully signed up, and will get **Signed up** if it failed.

I assumed that this means if the `function` signup ran successfully, that means the sign up was successful so the message should be **Signed up**

But if I do use **!** in the `if` statement like this:

```
if(!$signup->signup(...)){
echo "Signed up";
}
else{
echo "Signup failed";
}
```

In this case **Signed up** will be echoed if the data were correct and the signup was successful as it should be.

Don't misunderstand my question,the code works properly, there's no error, I'm just curious why it works this way.

Thanks for any answers!

PS:**The codes above are not complete code**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `signup()` method has no `return` statement, so it returns `null` by default, which is falsey. You need to return an indication of whether the query was successful.

```
function signup($username,$password){
    $res=$this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES(?,?)");
    $res->bindparam(1,$username);
    $res->bindparam(2,$password); 
    return $res->execute();
}
```